# How to avoid sharing of app programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing a custom app  therefore I don’t want unauthorized distribution of app either via Bluetooth or any other source. How to secure its .apk file pro grammatically from distribution?

Comment: May I ask why you aren't securing the app enough that distribution is not an issue.  Assuming users are authenticating against some server with rovocable credentials you are more than able to control access enough that it shouldn't matter what the application is run from.  If this is an app that has access without authentication you really should use the approach listed by Mr.Me to ensure the application is properly licensed against a licensing server in your corporate environment.

Comment: Yes i agree with you basically It is a complete system running on Dynamics AX . we just don't want to complicate it by introducing login system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to that is by using android license library.

**Note**: By doing so you will not be able to block sharing the **apk** it self, instead your app will know if it has been legally installed or not from the *play store* and take actions based on that. usually I just notify the user to download the app from the market and exit the app if it was not licensed.

here is a link to Android License Library [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) which includes an example

Comment: Please note while Mr.Me's solution works best with the play store.  You are able to create your own licencing server to verify the application against.  If you're aiming for correctness this is the solution you want to use.

Comment: OK i can consider it. does Google play provide that facility? I thought about the customize server but this will increase the work load outside android and also corporate don't want to favor this.

Comment: If your IT department doesn't want to secure the application using proper infrastructure then you are only obligated to ensure that they are aware of the risks associated with not doing so (get signoff).  Anything done client side to mitigate the app from redistribution can be removed.

Comment: As long as you are not considering distributing outside google play , the licensing library should be enough, else as Sparksis mentioned you will have to build your own licensing system

Answer (score 0):

You have to obfuscate & optimize your application, it's the only way...

If your application is good, unfortunatelly you'll find the .APK in several weeks on Internet ! :(

Use the last **[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)** tool to do this !

Comment: I want to secure it's apk distribution from one device to another via Bluetooth or other back up apps? how to do this?

Comment: I believe dan is looking for a method ensuring his enterprise application and therefore more concerned about device activation as opposed to copyright infringement.  He likely would like to distribute the device to corporate users whom then are unable to give access to their friends (corporate spies).  While obfuscation would help in this matter it would appear he's trying harder to stop the distribution before it happens.  I agree with you however, and my solution lacks the same ability to actually stop distribution but it rather aims at ensuring the app is worthless without activation.

Comment: Sparksis, you got my point and i did enough searching but no fruitful result has come across. so what should be done as an alternate in this case? There can be a solution like the corporate should put some high security. Or it should be the responsibility of IT and network department? Is that so?